# How do I fix Shopify GraphQL error :"Online Store channel is locked."

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

On a Shopify theme that I am developing, the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools shows that a request for `/api/graphql` returns status code 400 and this error message: 
`{"error":"Online Store channel is locked."}`

The payload for this request was:

```
{
  shop {
    paymentSettings {
      currencyCode
    }
  }
  node(id: "Z2lkO....") {
    ... on ProductVariant {
      requiresShipping
      price
      presentmentPrices(first: 25) {
        edges {
          node {
            price {
              amount
              currencyCode
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this failing and how do I fix it?